# Beginning to use wordpress, custom theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming

I'm pretty new to wordpress (only a couple of days), but I have it up and running on my website with the default theme. First of all I would like to change this theme. I have found a tutorial directly from wordpress but it is extremely vague: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development. I'd like to have a totally different layout for my website though, with only one page being replaced daily with a different article - a new article everyday basically. But I don't know where to start. I want to first create the theme though, I think that will put things in to perspective. How do I do so? I know the principles of php and enough about html and css to create whole websites. Thank you

Comment: ^ What he said. Please start accepting correct answers, or people will not be inclined to help you :)

Comment: yeah, I only just noticed the tick to be honest. thanks for telling me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link should tell you everything you need to know. You basically just edit the theme files to get the layout that you want. The best way to learn truly is to experiment. If you have a specific question I could help you with that, but to tell everything involved in creating a custom theme would go way beyond the scope of an answer for this site.

Comment: OK, which theme are you talking of editing? Do you know where I could download it?
Thanks

Comment: You can edit any theme that you want. For example, say that I wanted to edit the default 2010 theme. I would edit the files in /wp-content/themes/twentyten. If I took and found a theme online that I liked and wanted to modify, say I found it at http://wordpressthemesbase.com/, I would download it, place the extracted archive into /wp-content/themes and then edit the files to my liking.

Comment: Also, this may be better asked on the wordpress stack exchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/